# Self-signed certificate with private IP for IIS Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, iis, openssl, ssl-certificate, lan

I've generated a self-signed certificate with Open SSL to use in a **application** that runs on **IIS** which authenticates users via **Integrated Windows Authentication** method.

However there is a limiting factor that is impacting the auth method that is the **lack of DNS**.

When there is no WAN the LAN lacks the ability to resolve hostnames and the clients cannot connect to the server without using direct IP or by registering the alias in the hosts file.

**Chrome** does not allow to use the **Integrated Windows Auth** method and **shows a pop-up** to authenticate the user. However not having the connection to the WAN makes the pop-up to keep being shown and never really authenticates the user.

Accessing the application in the own server allows the auth method to work when the domain is added to the hostname in the URL. However this only works for the server itself and not for the other computers in the network.

In the certificate I added the **CN as the private IP** of the server and also added it at the **SAN**, but it did not work. Chrome keeps showing the pop-up. Also added the certificate in client's machine in the **Trusted Root Certificates**.

In this scenario is it possible to make Chrome to recognize the certificate and allow this auth method to work or this won't work at all?

Comment: Windows authentication without DNS? How did you set up the machines? Without a domain?

Comment: It has a domain while there js WAN. The app is meant to work as a Contingency system when there is no connection to the WAN, but unfortunately the LAN has its limitations. By WAN I mean a corporate network provided by a ISP. When it is connected to the WAN, the auth system works perfectly in all machines jn the LAN, but when the enlace is down it loses the ability to authenticate the client machines.

Comment: Escalate such to your network administrators/domain administrators please, because they know the correct solutions. Besides, Windows authentication is never a good option for WAN scenarios.

Comment: Chrome won't allow self-signed cert even though it has SAN and it is registered in the Trusted Root Certs? :( Network team said it is not possible to set a DNS server inside the local sites, so the Win Auth hasn't worked so far due to Chrome/Edge (Chromium...) requesting the credentials through the pop-up which doesn't auth at all.